# Integrating jQuery.validate and chosen.js

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-chosen

I am trying to setup validation on a form with a select dropdown generated by choosen.js

Here is my code:

```
$('.chzn-single').bind("change", function(){
     $myform.validate().element($(this));
});
```

I was thinkin something like that could work but I havent had any success. Any ideas out there??

Thanks

Comment: I think you'll need to provide some more details; like what you expect from validation (do they just have to select something?  or is it dependent on the value of another field?)  Also, exactly which validation library you're using (there's more than one).  Best would be to set up a jsFiddle with what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
This Code will check validation on submit and also when choosen change is fired.
$("#form").validate({
                errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                    if (element.is('select')) {
                        error.insertAfter(element.siblings(".chosen-container"));
                    } else {
                        error.insertAfter(element);
                    }
                },
                highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
                    $(element).next().addClass(errorClass);
                },
                unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
                    $(element).next().removeClass(errorClass);
                }
            });

            $(".chosen-select").chosen().change(function () {
                $("#form").validate().element(".chosen-select");
            });
```

Answer (score 8):

I have accomplished it by doing this:

```
var validator = $("#formid").data('validator');
validator.settings.ignore = ":hidden:not(select)";
```

By doing this, you will validate your hidden select field; chzn hides your default list and replaces it with its own.

Answer (score 5):

After having this problem for days, i found a way that worked for me.
You need to trigger the validation when chosen changes, this can be done with the .change() function. I used following code:

```
$("#chosenElement").chosen().change(function() {
        $("#myForm").validate().element("#chosenElement");
    });
```

I am using all the latest versions (jquery 1.9, jquery.validate 1.11.1, chosen 0.9.12)

Comment: If it never changes, it won't be validated.

Answer (score 5):

This is what I am using....

```
    $.validator.setDefaults({
        ignore: null, // you can use ":hidden:not(select)"
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            if(element.hasClass('chzn-done')) {
                var id = element.attr("id");
                $("#"+id+"_chzn a").addClass("error");
            }
        }
    });

    $('#myform').validate();//use your form ID or class selector

    $('select').chosen()
        .change(function () {
            var id = $(this).attr("id");
            if($(this).valid())
                $("#"+id+"_chzn a").removeClass("error");
            else
                $("#"+id+"_chzn a").addClass("error");
    });
```

and then in css

```
.chzn-container a.error {
    border-color: red !important;
}
```

Hope this helps....

Comment: I see `chzn-done` in previous version, strange that they removed it.

Comment: Yeah.. that answer was valid at the time it was posted. The world is changing everyday :)

Answer (score 4):

Try this.

On validate:

```js
ignore: function(index, element) {
    return !!$(element).parents(':hidden').length;
}
```

On chosen:

```js
$('.chosen-select').chosen().change(function() {
   $(this).trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: This absolutely works for the latest version of **Chosen** as of Nov, 2014. However, I also need to add the class `".error"` to the chosen elements. What's the best way to go about doing that?

Comment: Never mind. I got it solved. After using the solution @Daniel gives here, the parent `<li>` gets the class `selectError`. After that it's just styling.

Answer (score 1):

The easyist way to accomplish this is by using the following:

This will solve not only the issue of not being able to see the validation but it will also apply the standard **"input-validation-error"** class to the chosen.js styled select.

There are two cases where it needs to be applied both when the form is submitted and on a select change. See the three sections of code below.

1. The first sets the form validation to validate hidden elements.
2. The second checks the chosen validation on submit.
3. The third checks the chosen validation on a change.

**Sets up the form validation to show hidden:**

```
var validator = $("#FormID").data('validator');
validator.settings.ignore = ":hidden:not(select)";
```

**Checks on form submit:**

```
$('#FormID').on('submit', function () {
    var ChosenDropDowns = $('.chzn-done');
    ChosenDropDowns.each(function (index) {
        var ID = $(this).attr("id");
        if (!$(this).valid()) 
        {
            $("#" + ID + "_chzn a").addClass("input-validation-error");
        }
        else 
        {
            $("#" + ID + "_chzn a").removeClass("input-validation-error");
        }
    });
});
```

**Checks on select change:**

```
$(".chzn-select").chosen().change(function () {
    var ID = $(this).attr("id");
    if (!$(this).valid()) {
        $("#" + ID + "_chzn a").addClass("input-validation-error");
    }
    else {
        $("#" + ID + "_chzn a").removeClass("input-validation-error");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is ignoring the original select because it is hidden. I have gotten either:

```
$("#Form").data("validator").settings.ignore = "";
```

or

```
var settings = $.data($('#Form')[0], 'validator').settings;
settings.ignore += ':not(.chzn-done)';
```

to work.